# Matlab Naive Bayes

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, naivebayes

Hello Im using the KDD 1999 dataset and I was looking to apply naive bayes in matlab to it. What I want to know is the kdd dataset is a 494021x42 array of data, if you notice "training" and "target_class" below in the code for naive bayes:

```
training = [1;0;-1;-2;4;0]; % this is the sample data.
target_class = ['posi';'zero';'negi';'negi';'posi';'zero'];
    % This should have the same number of rows as training data but why?

% Training and Testing the classifier (between positive and negative)
test = 10*randn(10,1) % this is for testing. I am generating random numbers.
class  = classify(test,training, target_class, 'diaglinear')  
% This command classifies the test data depening on the given training data using a       Naive Bayes classifier

% diaglinear is for naive bayes classifier; there is also diagquadratic
```

What I would like to know is "Target_class" related to the kdd dataset attack types?

```
back dos
buffer_overflow u2r
ftp_write r2l
guess_passwd r2l
imap r2l
ipsweep probe
land dos
loadmodule u2r
multihop r2l
neptune dos
nmap probe
perl u2r
phf r2l
pod dos
portsweep probe
rootkit u2r
satan probe
smurf dos
spy r2l
teardrop dos
warezclient r2l
warezmaster r2l
```

Or is the target class the colum headers contained within the "test" set? i.e

```
protocol_type: symbolic.
service: symbolic.
flag: symbolic.
src_bytes: continuous.
dst_bytes: continuous.
land: symbolic.
wrong_fragment: continuous.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the task definition at, e.g. [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/databases/kddcup99/task.html), you'll see that the target classes are indeed the attack types. However the training set contains less attack types than the test set.

This is done for realism since after you train your intrusion detection algorithm it must be able to deal with new attack types which are close but not the same as existing ones.

Comment: strange, does that mean with the lower amount of attack types in the trainning set I might not get anything meaningful from the conclusion? You would think the test data would contain less and the trainning contain more for accuracy.

Comment: If you train you classification today you can only train on the attacks you have seen so far. It's reasonable to assume that new attacks, perhaps related to the existing ones, will appear in the future. It's your task to detect those as well!